# How bind mouse move to all scale widget?

Tags: tcl, scale, ttk

I am developping a Form generator on TCL TK.
I would bind a mouse move to all Scale widget.

I generate a scale widget:

```
grid [ttk::scale .frm.fgs_$name -length $length -from -100 -to 100 ] -column 2 -row $row -sticky w
```

I tried binding that doesn't works:

```
bind Scale <B1-Motion> {puts "Scale: %W"}
```

(also the `<Leave>` event doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example which worked for me:

```
bind   .c <Motion> {displayXY .info %x %y}
```

And you need a process to bind to.  Often you need to rescale 
the movement of the cursor.  In this case I create a cursor
that was a horizontal scale line traversing the Y-axis:

```
proc displayXY {w cx cy} {

  set x [expr {floor(double(($cx-$::dx)/50.))}]
  set y [expr {double((-$cy+$::dy))}]
  set ::cursorPosition [format "x=%.2f y=%.2f" $x $y]

  # remove old cursor "line"
  .c delete yTrace 

  ....much Cartesian math....

  # redraw new cursor "line"
  if { $y1 > -250   }  { 
    .c create line  $x1      $y1      $x2       $y2   -width 3  -fill grey60 -tags "yTrace"
    .c scale yTrace   0        0        1        -1
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, binding to a widget class is tricky since it affects *all* users of that widget, including ones that are in library code. It's not recommended, at least not with existing widget classes. (In contrast, it's a very good idea to do if you're making your own widget class.) For normal user code, it's better to either bind to the widget name:

```
bind .frm.fgs_$name <B1-Motion> {puts "Scale: %W"}
```

Or to bind to a new binding tag and install that:

```
# You're advised to begin custom binding tags with a lower-case letter
bind myScale <B1-Motion> {puts "Scale: %W"}
# Install after the instance-level bindings but before the class-level bindings
bindtags .frm.fgs_$name [linsert [bindtags .frm.fgs_$name] 1 myScale]
```

---

Your immediate problem is that `ttk::scale` uses the class name `TScale`. It also has an existing `<B1-Motion>` binding.